# Best way to scale up Bazel cache server?

Tags: bazel, buildfarm

I have set up a Bazel cache server in our company and have been using it quite smoothly. I simply followed the instruction [here](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/remote-caching.html#nginx) to set up a Nginx server. The underlying storage is on a solid state disk.

However, as our number of users grows, sometimes the cache server got stuck. I don't see any document talking about how to scale up to multiple cache servers. Any idea how to do that?

On top of my head, I could do the followings:

1. Run cache server on a dedicated machine, basically give it more resource,
2. Run multiple cache servers behind a Nginx load-balancer. But how does Nginx load-balancer interacts with bazel cache hash strategy? Will the same cache request be sent to the same cache server?
3. Switch to use [Bazel buildfarm](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel-buildfarm). But the problem remains, will the same build request be sent to the same remote worker?

Answer (score 0):

I think that buildfarm has solved the routing request problem (though not sure how).

I'd suggest asking this question on buildfarm's [mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/bazel-buildfarm).

Additionally you might be able to utilize GCS or S3 ([pending PR](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/pull/4889/)) as your caching backends since they are much more scalable (though I'm not sure about their latencies).